# WPF Treeview Binding, HOw do i display different data class as a Nodes Child?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

Im trying to display a group (file extension and icon)(parent) then all of the files found in that group (child) in a WPF Treeview. I can get the groups to show in the treeview, each with an icon and text, however I dont understand how to display the files as children of the group. Here is the GroupInfo class, the problem is it contains FileInfo a different class and all of the tutorials I have read so far on WPF treeview use only one data class to create tree items :

```
public class GroupInfo
{
    public GroupInfo()
    {
        alFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();
    }

    public string strExtension { get; set; }
    public ImageSource icon {get; set;}
    public string strDescription { get; set; }

    public string TypeDescription 
    {
        get
        {
            string s = strExtension;
            s.Replace('.',' ');
            s += " - " + strDescription;
            return s;
        }

        set
        {

        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> alFiles;

    void LoadIcon()
    {
        //icon = BitmapFrame.Create();
    }

    string GetDescription()
    {
        string strD = "";

        return strD;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to show all the FileInfo classes in alFiles as children of the group node. Here is my XAML :

```
<TreeView Margin="12,12,12,375" Name="trGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupInfo}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <Image Source="{Binding icon}"
                    Width="16" 
                   Height="16" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeDescription}" Margin="5,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileInfo}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Groups.Files}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <Image Source="{Binding icon}"
                    Width="16" 
                   Height="16" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeDescription}" Margin="5,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.  First, in your GroupInfo class, you should define a property for your `alFiles` field.  This is so that it could work with Bindings.

```
public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> alFiles;
public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> AlFiles { get { return alFiles;} }
```

Next, in your HierarchicalDataTemplate for GroupInfo the ItemsSource should be set to the `AlFiles` property.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupInfo}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AlFiles}">
```

Lastly, unless the FileInfo class has Children in them that you want to appear in the TreeView, you may want to change its template to just a `<DataTemplate>` instead of `<HierarchicalDataTemplate>`.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileInfo}">
...                
</DataTemplate>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou very much karmicpuppet that worked nicely. I have programmed in Win32/MFC/Windows Forms for years but i have decided to write my next app using WPF instead so am learning to use each control. Let me get this right then, for each child node you require a <HierarchicalDataTemplate> defining the datatype and itemsource, yes ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  But essentially, for each Type of hierarchical data you want to display in the treeview, you have to define a HierarchicalDataTemplate for it whose ItemsSource is set to the Children collection.

Comment: So for instance you have a Customer object with a collection of Orders.  Each Order object has a collection of Items.  In this case, you'll need two hierarchical data templates to display this in a treeview:  one for the Customer class (where ItemsSource={Binding Orders}), and one for the Order class (where ItemsSource={Binding Items}).  The Item class can be represented simply by a normal DataTemplate.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh thankyou thats exactly what I meant, sorry it was badly written. You have answered my question perfectly and I have the tree working exactly as I want it. I do like WPF binding, finally some intelligent users interface controls to use (I hate UI programming but WPF may change this).

Comment: Glad to know.  Yeah, WPF is a great framework, but yeah, I have to say it comes with a fairly steep learning curve.  But it's very rewarding to use.  So, good luck!  (By the way, can you please accept my answer above?  Thanks.)